# Changing part of a message's color in tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a TKinter messagebox like the one below. I would like to change **part** of the message to a different color. For example in the messagebox below I would like the language to be `Blue`. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't think you can change the properties of this Tkinter dialog.

Comment: You need to create your own message box: `Toplevel` + `Label` + `Button`. You can achieve it I think.

Comment: Or to use a Canvas and to draw your buttons, image and text...

Comment: Yep! I was going to add `Canvas` too.

Comment: I don't think you can change the colour of only a segment of a labeltext. What you could do is split the label into the "The languages of […]" part and a second, separate label for the language.

Comment: Yes, you need to separate text parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change such options of [Tkinter Standard Dialogs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm). You need to create your own dialog. You'll also need to separate the text parts. I've tried to make something similar in the image that the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480488/darthopto) has posted above:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def choosefunc(option):
    if option == "cancel":
        print("Cancel choosen")
    else:
        print("OK choosen")

def popupfunc():

    tl = Toplevel(root)
    tl.title("Languages")

    frame = Frame(tl)
    frame.grid()

    canvas = Canvas(frame, width=100, height=130)
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
    imgvar = PhotoImage(file="pyrocket.png")
    canvas.create_image(50,70, image=imgvar)
    canvas.image = imgvar

    msgbody1 = Label(frame, text="The", font=("Times New Roman", 20, "bold"))
    msgbody1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N)
    lang = Label(frame, text="language(s)", font=("Times New Roman", 20, "bold"), fg='blue')
    lang.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N)
    msgbody2 = Label(frame, text="of this country is: Arabic", font=("Times New Roman", 20, "bold"))
    msgbody2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=N)

    cancelbttn = Button(frame, text="Cancel", command=lambda: choosefunc("cancel"), width=10)
    cancelbttn.grid(row=2, column=3)

    okbttn = Button(frame, text="OK", command=lambda: choosefunc("ok"), width=10)
    okbttn.grid(row=2, column=4)

label = Label(root, text="Click to proceed:")
label.grid()

button = Button(root, text="Click", command=popupfunc)
button.grid()
```

(Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Nz1.jpg)